# Blank printing page with C# WinForm

Tags: c#, winforms, printing

After cautiously dragging and dropping `PrintDocument` from `Toolbox` to `Form1.cs[Design]`, and running the below code:

```
void printDocument1_PrintPage(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs e)
{
}

void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    CaptureScreen();
    printDocument1.Print();
    printDocument1.PrintPage += new 
    PrintPageEventHandler(printDocument1_PrintPage);
}

Bitmap memoryImage;

private void CaptureScreen()
{
    Graphics myGraphics = this.CreateGraphics();
    Size s = this.Size;
    memoryImage = new Bitmap(s.Width, s.Height, myGraphics);
    Graphics memoryGraphics = Graphics.FromImage(memoryImage);
    memoryGraphics.CopyFromScreen(this.Location.X, this.Location.Y, 0, 0, s);
}

void printDocument1_PrintPage_1(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs e)
{
    e.Graphics.DrawImage(memoryImage, 0, 0);
}
```

the printed page saved as `.pdf` is empty. Hence it looks like the `CaptureScreen() method` is not working somehow, although there is no errors in the code. Any feedback would be appreciated. Best

Comment: Doesn't the copy function require the top left most coordinates first? Might not, been a while since I used graphics

Comment: Just looking at the docs, are you trying to capture stuff that's outside the context of your current application? There are some flags you can pass as the final parameter to the method you are using. Though it looks like you are just trying to capture the current window

Comment: @Charleh: the idea consists of capturing the current window.

Comment: You have two PrintPage event handlers.  The one you actually use doesn't do anything.  So sure, blank page.  Keep your code tidy and you'll automatically avoid silly bugs like this.

Comment: @HansPassant: sure. Best.

Answer (score 0):

To draw the client area of a control, you can use to following snippet:

```
private Bitmap DrawToBitmap()
{
  using(Graphics g = this.CreateGraphics())
  {
    var bmp = new Bitmap(this.ClientSize.Width, this.ClientSize.Height, g);
    using(Graphics gBmp = Graphics.FromImage(bmp))
    {
      PaintEventArgs e = new PaintEventArgs(gBmp, this.ClientRectangle);
      this.OnPaint(e);        
    }        
  }
}
```